# Different instances of a System Verilog Module have different behaviour

Tags: logic, verilog, system-verilog

```
always @ (RSTDAC_B or EN or  DSR or  DSR_B )
        begin
            if (RSTDAC_B === 1'b0) begin stepp = 1'b0; stepn = 1'b0; end
       else if (RSTDAC_B === 1'b1) begin    
                 if (EN & DSR   === 1'b1)  begin stepn = 1'b1;end
             else if (EN & DSR_B  === 1'b1) begin stepp = 1'b1;end
                                    end
        end
```

The code above is from a Dynamic Register Module instantiated 8 times in the design. The intention is that when EN(able) is high then either stepp or stepn is high depending on if DSR or DSR_B is high. I am seeing that when DSR_B goes high, stepp and stepn BOTH go high in 6 out of 8 instances. In 2 instances, the design behaves as intended and only stepp goes high when EN & DSR_B are high.

I have seen this happen on multiple tools so I don't think its the tool's fault. Thanks

Comment: you describe a typical behavior which can be caused by glitches in state logic (you have a latch). Check for glitches at least in DSR.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid combinational logic. You must make assignments to all variables in all possible branches of your code. You are not doing that with `stepn` and `stepp`

If you are using SystemVerilog, you should be using `always_comb` instead of `always @(explicit_list_of_signals)`